# 440 Boost ASIO websocket connections take up 220k file descriptors

Tags: c++, boost, asio

I had posted this earlier but hadn't posted a proper minimum working example, apologies for that.

The problem is quite clear. Starting 440 websocket connections with Boost ASIO eats up about 220,000 file descriptors.

Here's how I come to that conclusion:
I sort each process by the number of file descriptors they eat use:
`lsof -n | awk '{print $2}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr`

My PID, 631457, comes out on top:
 `223504 631457` with 223k file descriptors in use. This is the code:

main.cpp:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    boost::asio::io_context ioctx;
    boost::asio::executor_work_guard<boost::asio::io_context::executor_type> workGuard =
        boost::asio::make_work_guard(ioctx.get_executor());

    // Initialise our IO working threads, 1 for each CPU core.
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<std::thread>> ioThreads;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 16; ++i) {
        ioThreads.push_back(std::make_shared<std::thread>([&ioctx]() { ioctx.run(); }));
    }

    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<WebSocketClient>> clients;
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<std::binary_semaphore>> semaphores;
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<std::thread>> clientThreads;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < 440; ++i){
        clients.push_back(std::make_shared<WebSocketClient>(ioctx,  "ws.postman-echo.com", 443, "/raw",  [](){}));
        semaphores.push_back(std::make_shared<std::binary_semaphore>(0));
        clients.back()->setMessageReceivedCallback([sem = semaphores.back()](){
            sem->release();
        });

        clientThreads.push_back(std::make_shared<std::thread>([index = i, sem = semaphores.back(), client = clients.back()](){
            size_t counter = 0;
            while(true){
                client->sendMessage(std::to_string(counter++));
                sem->acquire();
                auto message = client->readMessageIfAvailable();
                if(message) {
                    std::cout << index << " : " << message.value() << std::endl;
                }
            }
        }));
    }


    for (auto &thread : clientThreads) {
        thread->join();
    }

    for (auto &thread : ioThreads) {
        thread->join();
    }
}
```

WebsocketClient.h:

```
class WebSocketClient {
  public:
    /**
     *
     * @param host
     * @param port
     * @param path
     * @param connectionClosedCallback Signals the connection was closed. This function may NOT cause the destructor of
     * WebSocketClient to be called on this thread, since this will cause a deadlock. Always signal another thread.
     */
    WebSocketClient(boost::asio::io_context &ioctx, std::string host, uint16_t port, std::string path,
                    std::function<void()> connectionClosedCallback = std::function<void()>(),

                    std::string customKeepAliveMessage = "", unsigned int customKeepAliveMessageIntervalInMs = 0);

    ~WebSocketClient();

    WebSocketClient(WebSocketClient &&other) = delete;
    WebSocketClient(const WebSocketClient &other) = delete;
    WebSocketClient &operator=(WebSocketClient &&other) = delete;
    WebSocketClient &operator=(const WebSocketClient &other) = delete;

    bool sendMessage(std::string message);
    std::optional<std::string> readMessageIfAvailable();
    void setMessageReceivedCallback(std::function<void()> callback);
    void startClose();
    bool closed();

  private:
    void startCustomKeepAliveMessageTimer();
    void sendCustomKeepAliveMessage();

    void handleFailure(boost::beast::error_code ec, char const *what);
    void handleClose();
    void on_resolve(boost::beast::error_code ec, const boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::results_type &results);
    void on_connect(boost::beast::error_code ec, const boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::results_type::endpoint_type &ep);
    void on_ssl_handshake(boost::beast::error_code ec);
    void on_handshake(boost::beast::error_code ec);
    void startWrite();
    void writeCompleted(boost::beast::error_code ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred);
    void startRead();
    void readCompleted(boost::beast::error_code ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred);
    void on_close(boost::beast::error_code ec);

    boost::asio::io_context &ioContext;
    boost::asio::strand<boost::asio::io_context::executor_type> strand;

    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver_;
    boost::asio::ssl::context sslContext;
    boost::beast::websocket::stream<boost::beast::ssl_stream<boost::beast::tcp_stream>> ws_;
    std::string writeBuffer;
    boost::beast::flat_buffer readBuffer;
    std::string host;
    std::string port;
    std::string path;
    LockFreeQueue<std::string> writeQueue;
    LockFreeQueue<std::string> readQueue;
    bool writing;
    std::atomic<bool> closing;
    /// Must be captured by the lambda that will be executed on async job returning, pending jobs = .use_count() - 1
    std::shared_ptr<nullptr_t> asyncJobTracker;
    std::function<void()> connectionClosedCallback;

    boost::asio::steady_timer customKeepAliveTimer;
    std::string customKeepAliveMessage;
    unsigned int customKeepAliveMessageIntervalInMs;
};
```

WebsocketClient.cpp:

```
#include "WebSocketClient.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

//#include "CertificateManager.h"

WebSocketClient::WebSocketClient(boost::asio::io_context &ioctx,
                                 std::string host, uint16_t port, std::string path,
                                 std::function<void()> connectionClosedCallback,
                                 std::string customKeepAliveMessage,
                                 unsigned int customKeepAliveMessageIntervalInMs)
    : ioContext(ioctx),
      strand(boost::asio::make_strand(ioContext.get_executor())),
      customKeepAliveTimer(strand),
      resolver_(strand),
      sslContext(boost::asio::ssl::context::tlsv12_client),
      ws_(strand    , sslContext),
      writeBuffer(),
      readBuffer(),
      host(std::move(host)),
      port(std::to_string(port)),
      path(std::move(path)),
      writeQueue(128),
      readQueue(128),
      writing(true),
      closing(false),
      asyncJobTracker(std::make_shared<nullptr_t>()),
      connectionClosedCallback(std::move(connectionClosedCallback)),
      customKeepAliveMessage(customKeepAliveMessage),
      customKeepAliveMessageIntervalInMs(customKeepAliveMessageIntervalInMs)
{
//    boost::system::error_code ec;
//    ec = CertificateManager::getCertificateManager().loadRootCertificates(sslContext);
//    if (ec) {
//        handleFailure(ec, "loadRootCertificates");
//        return;
//    }
    resolver_.async_resolve(
        this->host, this->port,
        [this, asyncJobTracker = asyncJobTracker](const boost::beast::error_code ec,
                                                  const boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::results_type& results) {
            on_resolve(ec, results);
        });
}

WebSocketClient::~WebSocketClient() {
    startClose();
    if (asyncJobTracker.use_count() > 1) {
//        LogError <<"WEBSOCKET CONTAINS MAJOR ERROR, async functions not finished after destructor exit" << std::endl;
    }
}

void WebSocketClient::handleFailure(boost::beast::error_code ec, const char* what) {
    if (!closing) {
        closing = true;
//        LogInfo << std::string() + what + ": " + ec.message() + "\n" << std::endl;
    }
    handleClose();
}

void WebSocketClient::handleClose() {
    if (asyncJobTracker.use_count() > 2) {  // 1 for the member var, 1 for the function calling this.
        return;
    }
//    LogInfo << "Websocket connection closed" << std::endl;

    if (connectionClosedCallback) {
        connectionClosedCallback();
    }
}

void WebSocketClient::on_resolve(boost::beast::error_code ec,
                                 const boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::results_type& results) {
    if (ec) return handleFailure(ec, "resolve");

    // Set a timeout on the operation
    boost::beast::get_lowest_layer(ws_).expires_after(std::chrono::seconds(30));

    // Make the connection on the IP address we get from a lookup
    boost::beast::get_lowest_layer(ws_).async_connect(
        results, [this, asyncJobTracker = asyncJobTracker](
                     boost::beast::error_code ec,
                     const boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::results_type::endpoint_type& ep) { on_connect(ec, ep); });
}

void WebSocketClient::on_connect(boost::beast::error_code ec,
                                 const boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::results_type::endpoint_type& ep) {
    if (ec) return handleFailure(ec, "connect");

    // Set a timeout on the operation
    boost::beast::get_lowest_layer(ws_).expires_after(std::chrono::seconds(30));

    // Set SNI Hostname (many hosts need this to handshake successfully)
    if (!SSL_set_tlsext_host_name(ws_.next_layer().native_handle(), host.c_str())) {
        ec = boost::beast::error_code(static_cast<int>(::ERR_get_error()), boost::asio::error::get_ssl_category());
        return handleFailure(ec, "connect");
    }

    // Update the host_ string. This will provide the value of the
    // Host HTTP header during the WebSocket handshake.
    // See https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-5.4
    host += ':' + std::to_string(ep.port());

    // Perform the SSL handshake
    ws_.next_layer().async_handshake(
        boost::asio::ssl::stream_base::client,
        [this, asyncJobTracker = asyncJobTracker](boost::beast::error_code ec) { on_ssl_handshake(ec); });
}

void WebSocketClient::on_ssl_handshake(boost::beast::error_code ec) {
    if (ec) return handleFailure(ec, "ssl_handshake");

    // Turn off the timeout on the tcp_stream, because
    // the boost::beast::websocket stream has its own timeout system.
    boost::beast::get_lowest_layer(ws_).expires_never();

    // Set suggested timeout settings for the boost::beast::websocket
    ws_.set_option(boost::beast::websocket::stream_base::timeout::suggested(boost::beast::role_type::client));

    // Set a decorator to change the User-Agent of the handshake
    ws_.set_option(boost::beast::websocket::stream_base::decorator(
        [](boost::beast::websocket::request_type& req) { req.set(boost::beast::http::field::user_agent, "Agnes"); }));

    // Perform the boost::beast::websocket handshake
    ws_.async_handshake(host, path,
                        [this, asyncJobTracker = asyncJobTracker](boost::beast::error_code ec) { on_handshake(ec); });
}

void WebSocketClient::on_handshake(boost::beast::error_code ec) {
    if (ec) return handleFailure(ec, "handshake");
    writing = false;
    startWrite();
    startRead();

    if(customKeepAliveMessage != "")
    {
        startCustomKeepAliveMessageTimer();
    }
}

void WebSocketClient::startWrite() {
    if (writing || closing) {
        return;
    }
    if (!writeQueue.dequeue(&writeBuffer)) {
        return;
    }

    writing = true;
    ws_.async_write(boost::asio::buffer(writeBuffer), [this, asyncJobTracker = asyncJobTracker](
                                                          boost::beast::error_code ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred) {
        writeCompleted(ec, bytes_transferred);
    });
}

void WebSocketClient::writeCompleted(boost::beast::error_code ec, std::size_t /*bytes_transferred*/) {
    if (ec) return handleFailure(ec, "write");
    writing = false;
    startWrite();
}

void WebSocketClient::startRead() {
    ws_.async_read(readBuffer, [this, asyncJobTracker = asyncJobTracker](boost::beast::error_code ec,
                                                                         std::size_t bytes_transferred) {
        readCompleted(ec, bytes_transferred);
    });
}

void WebSocketClient::readCompleted(boost::beast::error_code ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred) {
    if (ec) return handleFailure(ec, "read");

    readQueue.enqueue({boost::asio::buffer_cast<const char*>(readBuffer.data()), readBuffer.size()});
    readBuffer.consume(bytes_transferred);
    startRead();
}

void WebSocketClient::startClose() {
    if (closing) {
        return;
    }
    closing = true;
    boost::asio::post(strand, [this, asyncJobTracker = asyncJobTracker]() {
        ws_.async_close(boost::beast::websocket::close_code::normal,
                        [this, asyncJobTracker = asyncJobTracker](boost::beast::error_code ec) { on_close(ec); });
    });
}

void WebSocketClient::on_close(boost::beast::error_code ec) {
    if (ec) return handleFailure(ec, "close");
    handleClose();
}

bool WebSocketClient::sendMessage(std::string message) {
    if (writeQueue.enqueue(std::move(message))) {
        boost::asio::post(strand, [this, asyncJobTracker = asyncJobTracker]() { startWrite(); });
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

std::optional<std::string> WebSocketClient::readMessageIfAvailable() {
    std::string message;
    return (readQueue.dequeue(&message) ? message : std::optional<std::string>());
}

void WebSocketClient::setMessageReceivedCallback(std::function<void()> callback) {
    readQueue.setNewMessageWrittenCallback(std::move(callback));
}

bool WebSocketClient::closed() {
    return closing;
}

void WebSocketClient::startCustomKeepAliveMessageTimer() {
    boost::asio::post(strand, [this]() {
        customKeepAliveTimer.expires_after(std::chrono::milliseconds(customKeepAliveMessageIntervalInMs)); // Set ping interval
        customKeepAliveTimer.async_wait([this](const boost::system::error_code& ec) {
            if (!ec) {
                sendCustomKeepAliveMessage();
            }
        });
    });
}

void WebSocketClient::sendCustomKeepAliveMessage() {
    if (!closing) {
        sendMessage(customKeepAliveMessage);
        startCustomKeepAliveMessageTimer();  // Restart the timer for the next ping
    }
}
```

To reduce the amount of code posted here I have not included the implementation of the LockFreeQueue but I have tested this class thoroughly. The problem does not lie there.

Furthermore, the WebsocketClient class implementation is very heavily based on the [boost example](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/libs/beast/example/websocket/client/async/websocket_client_async.cpp)

I expect the websocket connections to take up some file descriptors, but this is an astronomical amount.

Comment: This is way too much code to wade through for SO. I suggest you start by running your code with only a few connections under `strace` (or the modern DTrace tooling) to see when (and why) it creates new file descriptors, and also to inspect `/proc/$pid/fd` and the output of `ss` to see what they all point to. (files or network addresses)

Comment: Yeah sorry @Botje, I wanted to provide a good working example this time since last time the question was closed immediately for that reason but I understand it is a very large amount of code. 

Thanks for the suggestions, I will do that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is likely in code not shown. I made the code self-contained (admittedly butchering some of the logic, but hey, it needs to compile):

- File `WebSocketClient.h`

  ```
   #pragma once
   #include <boost/asio.hpp>
   #include <boost/beast.hpp>
   #include <boost/beast/ssl.hpp>
   #include <deque>
   namespace asio      = boost::asio;
   namespace ssl       = asio::ssl;
   namespace beast     = boost::beast;
   namespace websocket = beast::websocket;
   using asio::ip::tcp;
   using boost::beast::error_code;

   template <typename T> struct LockFreeQueue {
       LockFreeQueue(int) {}
       LockFreeQueue(LockFreeQueue&& rhs) {
           std::unique_lock               //
               lk1(_mx, std::defer_lock), //
               lk2(rhs._mx, std::defer_lock);
           std::lock(lk1, lk2);
           std::swap(rhs._impl, _impl);
       }

       bool enqueue(T v) {
           std::lock_guard lk(_mx);
           _impl.push_back(std::move(v));
           if (_cb) {
               _cb();
           }
           return true;
       }

       bool dequeue(T* v) {
           assert(v);
           std::lock_guard lk(_mx);
           if (_impl.empty())
               return false;
           if (v)
               *v = std::move(_impl.front());
           _impl.pop_front();
           return true;
       };

       void setNewMessageWrittenCallback(auto f) {
           std::lock_guard lk(_mx);
           _cb = std::move(f);
       }

     private:
       std::deque<T> _impl;
       std::mutex mutable _mx;
       std::function<void()> _cb;
   };

   class WebSocketClient {
     public:
       WebSocketClient(asio::io_context& ioctx, std::string host, uint16_t port, std::string path,
                       std::function<void()> connectionClosedCallback           = std::function<void()>(),
                       std::string           customKeepAliveMessage             = "",
                       unsigned int          customKeepAliveMessageIntervalInMs = 0);

       ~WebSocketClient();

       WebSocketClient(WebSocketClient&&)                 = delete;
       WebSocketClient(WebSocketClient const&)            = delete;
       WebSocketClient& operator=(WebSocketClient&&)      = delete;
       WebSocketClient& operator=(WebSocketClient const&) = delete;

       bool                       sendMessage(std::string message);
       std::optional<std::string> readMessageIfAvailable();
       void                       setMessageReceivedCallback(std::function<void()> callback);
       void                       startClose();
       bool                       closed();

     private:
       void startCustomKeepAliveMessageTimer();
       void sendCustomKeepAliveMessage();

       using endpoints = tcp::resolver::results_type;
       void handleFailure(error_code ec, char const* what);
       void handleClose();
       void on_resolve(error_code ec, endpoints const& results);
       void on_connect(error_code ec, tcp::endpoint const& ep);
       void on_ssl_handshake(error_code ec);
       void on_handshake(error_code ec);
       void startWrite();
       void writeCompleted(error_code ec, size_t bytes_transferred);
       void startRead();
       void readCompleted(error_code ec, size_t bytes_transferred);
       void on_close(error_code ec);

       asio::io_context&                             ioContext;
       asio::strand<asio::io_context::executor_type> strand;

       tcp::resolver                                           resolver_;
       ssl::context                                            sslContext;
       websocket::stream<beast::ssl_stream<beast::tcp_stream>> ws_;
       std::string                                             writeBuffer;
       beast::flat_buffer                                      readBuffer;
       std::string                                             host;
       std::string                                             port;
       std::string                                             path;
       LockFreeQueue<std::string>                              writeQueue;
       LockFreeQueue<std::string>                              readQueue;
       bool                                                    writing;
       std::atomic_bool                                        closing;
       /// Must be captured by the lambda that will be executed on async job returning, pending jobs =
       /// .use_count() - 1
       std::shared_ptr<void const> asyncJobTracker;
       std::function<void()>       connectionClosedCallback;

       asio::steady_timer customKeepAliveTimer;
       std::string        customKeepAliveMessage;
       unsigned int       customKeepAliveMessageIntervalInMs;
   };
  ```
- File `WebSocketClient.cpp`

  ```
   #include "WebSocketClient.h"

   #include <iostream>
   #include <utility>

   // #include "CertificateManager.h"
   //
   static std::ostream LogInfo(std::cout.rdbuf());
   static std::ostream LogError(std::cerr.rdbuf());

   WebSocketClient::WebSocketClient(asio::io_context& ioctx, std::string host, uint16_t port, std::string path,
                                    std::function<void()> connectionClosedCallback,
                                    std::string           customKeepAliveMessage,
                                    unsigned int          customKeepAliveMessageIntervalInMs)
       : ioContext(ioctx)
       , strand(asio::make_strand(ioContext.get_executor()))
       , resolver_(strand)
       , sslContext(ssl::context::tlsv12_client)
       , ws_(strand, sslContext)
       , host(std::move(host))
       , port(std::to_string(port))
       , path(std::move(path))
       , writeQueue(128)
       , readQueue(128)
       , writing(true)
       , closing(false)
       , connectionClosedCallback(std::move(connectionClosedCallback))
       , customKeepAliveTimer(strand)
       , customKeepAliveMessage(customKeepAliveMessage)
       , customKeepAliveMessageIntervalInMs(customKeepAliveMessageIntervalInMs) {
       //    error_code ec;
       //    ec = CertificateManager::getCertificateManager().loadRootCertificates(sslContext);
       //    if (ec) {
       //        handleFailure(ec, "loadRootCertificates");
       //        return;
       //    }
       resolver_.async_resolve(
           this->host, this->port,
           [this, asyncJobTracker = asyncJobTracker](error_code ec, endpoints const& results) {
               on_resolve(ec, results);
           });
   }

   WebSocketClient::~WebSocketClient() {
       startClose();
       if (asyncJobTracker.use_count() > 1) {
           LogError << "WEBSOCKET CONTAINS MAJOR ERROR, async functions not finished after destructor exit"
                    << std::endl;
       }
   }

   void WebSocketClient::handleFailure(error_code ec, char const* what) {
       if (!closing) {
           closing = true;
           LogInfo << std::string() + what + ": " + ec.message() + "\n" << std::endl;
       }
       handleClose();
   }

   void WebSocketClient::handleClose() {
       if (asyncJobTracker.use_count() > 2) { // 1 for the member var, 1 for the function calling this.
           return;
       }
       LogInfo << "Websocket connection closed" << std::endl;

       if (connectionClosedCallback) {
           connectionClosedCallback();
       }
   }

   void WebSocketClient::on_resolve(error_code ec, endpoints const& results) {
       if (ec)
           return handleFailure(ec, "resolve");

       // Set a timeout on the operation
       beast::get_lowest_layer(ws_).expires_after(std::chrono::seconds(30));

       // Make the connection on the IP address we get from a lookup
       beast::get_lowest_layer(ws_).async_connect(
           results, [this, asyncJobTracker = asyncJobTracker](error_code ec, tcp::endpoint const& ep) {
               on_connect(ec, ep);
           });
   }

   void WebSocketClient::on_connect(error_code ec, tcp::endpoint const& ep) {
       if (ec)
           return handleFailure(ec, "connect");

       // Set a timeout on the operation
       beast::get_lowest_layer(ws_).expires_after(std::chrono::seconds(30));

       // Set SNI Hostname (many hosts need this to handshake successfully)
       if (!SSL_set_tlsext_host_name(ws_.next_layer().native_handle(), host.c_str())) {
           ec = error_code(static_cast<int>(::ERR_get_error()), asio::error::get_ssl_category());
           return handleFailure(ec, "connect");
       }

       // Update the host_ string. This will provide the value of the
       // Host HTTP header during the WebSocket handshake.
       // See https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-5.4
       host += ':' + std::to_string(ep.port());

       // Perform the SSL handshake
       ws_.next_layer().async_handshake(
           ssl::stream_base::client,
           [this, asyncJobTracker = asyncJobTracker](error_code ec) { on_ssl_handshake(ec); });
   }

   void WebSocketClient::on_ssl_handshake(error_code ec) {
       if (ec)
           return handleFailure(ec, "ssl_handshake");

       // Turn off the timeout on the tcp_stream, because
       // the websocket stream has its own timeout system.
       beast::get_lowest_layer(ws_).expires_never();

       // Set suggested timeout settings for the websocket
       ws_.set_option(websocket::stream_base::timeout::suggested(beast::role_type::client));

       // Set a decorator to change the User-Agent of the handshake
       ws_.set_option(websocket::stream_base::decorator(
           [](websocket::request_type& req) { req.set(beast::http::field::user_agent, "Agnes"); }));

       // Perform the websocket handshake
       ws_.async_handshake(host, path,
                           [this, asyncJobTracker = asyncJobTracker](error_code ec) { on_handshake(ec); });
   }

   void WebSocketClient::on_handshake(error_code ec) {
       if (ec)
           return handleFailure(ec, "handshake");
       writing = false;
       startWrite();
       startRead();

       if (customKeepAliveMessage != "") {
           startCustomKeepAliveMessageTimer();
       }
   }

   void WebSocketClient::startWrite() {
       if (writing || closing) {
           return;
       }
       if (!writeQueue.dequeue(&writeBuffer)) {
           return;
       }

       writing = true;
       ws_.async_write(asio::buffer(writeBuffer),
                       [this, asyncJobTracker = asyncJobTracker](error_code ec, size_t bytes_transferred) {
                           writeCompleted(ec, bytes_transferred);
                       });
   }

   void WebSocketClient::writeCompleted(error_code ec, size_t /*bytes_transferred*/) {
       if (ec)
           return handleFailure(ec, "write");
       writing = false;
       startWrite();
   }

   void WebSocketClient::startRead() {
       ws_.async_read(readBuffer,
                      [this, asyncJobTracker = asyncJobTracker](error_code ec, size_t bytes_transferred) {
                          readCompleted(ec, bytes_transferred);
                      });
   }

   void WebSocketClient::readCompleted(error_code ec, size_t bytes_transferred) {
       if (ec)
           return handleFailure(ec, "read");

       readQueue.enqueue({asio::buffer_cast<char const*>(readBuffer.data()), readBuffer.size()});
       readBuffer.consume(bytes_transferred);
       startRead();
   }

   void WebSocketClient::startClose() {
       if (closing) {
           return;
       }
       closing = true;
       asio::post(strand, [this, asyncJobTracker = asyncJobTracker]() {
           ws_.async_close(websocket::close_code::normal,
                           [this, asyncJobTracker = asyncJobTracker](error_code ec) { on_close(ec); });
       });
   }

   void WebSocketClient::on_close(error_code ec) {
       if (ec)
           return handleFailure(ec, "close");
       handleClose();
   }

   bool WebSocketClient::sendMessage(std::string message) {
       if (writeQueue.enqueue(std::move(message))) {
           asio::post(strand, [this, asyncJobTracker = asyncJobTracker]() { startWrite(); });
           return true;
       }
       return false;
   }

   std::optional<std::string> WebSocketClient::readMessageIfAvailable() {
       std::string message;
       return (readQueue.dequeue(&message) ? message : std::optional<std::string>());
   }

   void WebSocketClient::setMessageReceivedCallback(std::function<void()> callback) {
       readQueue.setNewMessageWrittenCallback(std::move(callback));
   }

   bool WebSocketClient::closed() { return closing; }

   void WebSocketClient::startCustomKeepAliveMessageTimer() {
       asio::post(strand, [this]() {
           customKeepAliveTimer.expires_after(
               std::chrono::milliseconds(customKeepAliveMessageIntervalInMs)); // Set ping interval
           customKeepAliveTimer.async_wait([this](error_code ec) {
               if (!ec) {
                   sendCustomKeepAliveMessage();
               }
           });
       });
   }

   void WebSocketClient::sendCustomKeepAliveMessage() {
       if (!closing) {
           sendMessage(customKeepAliveMessage);
           startCustomKeepAliveMessageTimer(); // Restart the timer for the next ping
       }
   }
  ```
- File `test.cpp`

  ```
   #include "WebSocketClient.h"
   #include <iostream>
   #include <list>

   int main() {
       asio::io_context ioctx;
       auto             workGuard = make_work_guard(ioctx.get_executor());

       // Initialise our IO working threads, 1 for each CPU core.
       std::list<std::thread> ioThreads;
       for (size_t i = 0; i < 16; ++i)
           ioThreads.emplace_back([&ioctx]() { ioctx.run(); });

       struct Client {
           std::unique_ptr<WebSocketClient>       client;
           std::unique_ptr<std::binary_semaphore> sem;
           std::thread                            thread;
       };

       std::list<Client> clients;
       for (size_t i = 0; i < 440; ++i) {
           auto& [pclient, psem, thread] = clients.emplace_back();

           pclient      = std::make_unique<WebSocketClient>(ioctx, "ws.postman-echo.com", 443, "/raw", []() {});
           auto& client = *pclient;

           psem         = std::make_unique<std::binary_semaphore>(0);
           auto& sem    = *psem;

           client.setMessageReceivedCallback([&sem] { sem.release(); });
           thread = std::thread([index = i, &sem, &client] {
               size_t counter = 0;
               while (true) {
                   client.sendMessage(std::to_string(counter++));
                   sem.acquire();
                   auto message = client.readMessageIfAvailable();
                   if (message) {
                       std::cout << index << " : " << message.value() << std::endl;
                   }
               }
           });
       }

       for (auto& c : clients)
           if (c.thread.joinable())
               c.thread.join();

       workGuard.reset();
       for (auto& thread : ioThreads)
           if (thread.joinable())
               thread.join();
   }
  ```

Running it on my system opens 446 filedescriptors total, 440 tcp:

[image]

Comment: [There are unrelated issues with the code which I'll be ignoring for now.]

Comment: Updated code to actually wire up the read callback so we have actual traffic happening as well.

Comment: Thanks a ton @sehe, this is a huge help in figuring out what the issue is.

Comment: Could you maybe give some pointers on the other issues you mentioned, so that I can look into them myself?

Comment: @Max In a rare moment of moderation/self-preservation I've not looked at it all to make an exhaustive list (this is my default mode when reading SO question code...). The one that sticks out in my memory is that you use a dynamic read buffer that you consume according to `bytes_transferred`, but you accumulate the full buffer contents, even if it is more than that.

Comment: thanks for the pointer. 

I've ran the exact code you gave. When running `ss -p` I do indeed get the same results as you: 440 TCP sockets open. 

However, when running `lsof -n | awk '{print $2}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr` I get the same results as before: 

https://imgur.com/a/TZtKigI